# Constrain a columns value to a value of a different column inside the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a tree view for a website using databases. I will create 2 tables, let's call them "Folder" and "File". A folder can contain multiple folders and files, and files will act as leaf nodes - which means they're a "dead end" in the tree if you're unfamiliar with the term.

The folder table will contain columns:

```
Folder_id, Folder_name, Folder_parent
```

File will contain:

```
File_id, File_name, File_parent
```

Obviously File_parent will reference a folder_id, thus creating a foreign key, but how do I make the Folder_parent reference the Folder_id?

Example:

```
FOLDER_NAME   | FOLDER_ID   | FOLDER_PARENT
root               1               null 
Cars               2                 1 
Planes             3                 1 
BMW                4                 2
```

Comment: I think your missing the point, file_parent is already pointing to the folder_id, so when looking at a folder you do select file_id where folder_name = 'example'

Comment: @Abe When creating a file it's easy to make sure it doesn't have a nonexistent parent as the file_parent references folder_id. But when creating a folder, a similar failsafe doesn't exist. I could just check that the id is valid before the insert (Select * from folder where folder_id = parameter, if any are found proceed), but isn't there a more.. table side solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table folder (
  folder_id int primary key,
  folder_name varchar not null,
  folder_parent int references folder(folder_id)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a separate table to deal with relationships, since a file can easily exist in two folders (think aliases). In this schema, you could simplify things with just a `node` table and a `relationships` (or `edges`, if you're familiar with graph theory) table:

```
CREATE TABLE nodes (
    node_id int primary key,
    node_name varchar not null,
    node_type enum('folder','file')
)

CREATE TABLE edges (
    child_node_id int primary key,
    parent_node_id int,
    unique( child_node_id, parent_node_id)
)
```

I'm a little rusty on my sql, so my syntax may need some work, but that's how I would approach it. It's much more flexible this way.